# Solr : Return documents that start with query keywords

Tags: search, solr

I am using solr for indexing some documents and then searching. I want to return those documents that have the same start as the search keywords higher in the results. How can i achieve that?

E.g.

If i the search keyword is "php"

and there are two documents with content :

- php developer
- ajax php

then i want to return 'php developer' first instead of 'ajax php'.

Any suggestions on how to return results in this order?

I am looking for some sort of an analyzer that only indexes the first word from the content of a field and then giving that field a lot of weight while querying. Maybe that can help. I couldnt find such an analyzer for my purposes.

Comment: Was the answer below useful to solve your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can boost the first tokens using payload. Refer to the link mentioned in [Payloads](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Payloads)